# Finding an particular document inside an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have an app which has a collection of users and it stores notes for each particular user inside an array:

[My collection of users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmsNw.png)

[The array of notes of one person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXEWR.png)

If I have the id of the note and the user to whom the note belongs to, how can i query for that specific note and ($pull/delete) it.
I have tried to find the correct query for it but to no avail:

```
app.get('/delete/:userId/:noteId', (req,res)=>{
let noteId = req.params.noteId;
User.findOne({'notes': {_id: noteId}},(err,foundNote)=>{
    console.log(foundNote);
});
```

});

What I am looking for is a the condition I need to set for finding that particular note document. Thank you in advance :).

Answer (score 1):

you can use $pull :

```
app.get('/delete/:userId/:noteId', (req,res)=>{
   let noteId = req.params.noteId;
   let userId= req.params.userId;
   User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $pull: { notes: noteId  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ObjectId, your filter will be:

{ 'notes._id': ObjectId(noteId) }